# ImportError using python if __name__ == "__main__"

Tags: django, python-2.7

I currently inherited a codebase that looks something like this.

```
project
manage.py
   |_ config
           |_ settings
           |_ wsgi.py
   |_ project
            |_ app1
            |_ app2
            |.... <-- many more Django apps
            |_ a_new_app
                 |_ __init__.py                  
                 |_ run.py
                 |_ foo.py
                 |_ bar.py
```

I added a new app with some `.py` files which imports from other apps too in the same package and other app packages too in the project. All is well till I tried to run

```
python project/a_new_app/run.py
```

Then I started getting import error here is how my `run.py` looks.

```
# run.py
from project.a_new_app.foo import Foo

class App():
    def method(self, key):
        data = {"some-key": Foo}
        return data.get(key)

    .... more methods here

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.loop_forever()
```

I got this error

```
File "project/a_new_app/run.py", line 7, in <module>
    from project.a_new_app.foo import Foo
ImportError: No module named project.a_new_app.foo
```

My working directory is `/user/me/PycharmProjects/project`, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from project.a_new_app.foo import Foo
```

For this import to work, you need the outer `project` directory (the one containing `manage.py` and the inner `project` directory) to be on the Python path.

However, `run.py` is two directories deeper than that, in `project/a_new_app`. Therefore you need to add `../..` to the python path at the top of the module.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../..')

from project.a_new_app.foo import Foo
...
```

Comment: *It does not work* is not enough information to help you.  `../..` might not be correct for your actual project layout, but the general approach is - you can only import `project.a_new_app.foo` if you add the directory containing `project` to the python path. Make sure that the inner `project` and `a_new_app` directories both contain `__init__.py` files.